# How to compute acute triangles and their values from sections of a circle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, arc-length, programming

I am working with a sensor that outputs data in forms of radial beams. In order for it to be useful for my application I have to compute a value of one side of the acute triangles that can be seen in the radial beams. Inside these triangles I can then check whether or not an obstacle is seen. Here's the diagram (sorry about the quality, I tried my best):

[image]

*Figure 1.*

Conditions:

1. Assume *α* = *β*.
2. Assume the segments and their angles aren't up to scale.
3. Assume there are 16 radial segments (or arcs), first one perpendicular to the Y-axis, the last one is parallel with the X-axis, and that the angles subtended by the arcs are all equal.
4. Assume the radii and the angles of the arcs are known.
5. Assume **TU** is known.

The problem:

How would one calculate triangles' side created within the segments? For example, let's take triangles **CAR** and **RAP** (the names are accidental!), is it possible to calculate their sides, especially the opposites of the angles *α* and *β*, **CR** and **RP**?

My current idea is to use **TU**, form right angle triangles such as **APJ** (imagine if **T** was overlaying **P**) and use the angles known to calculate the remaining sides. The problem with that is it becomes increasingly complex for increasing number of segments.

Is there a better way of doing it, keeping in mind that it's a part of a obstacle detection algorithm?

EDIT 1: got rid of a redundant line, updated the diagram.

EDIT 2: extra question: imagine arc *c* being absent and the first arc is actually arc *d* (so no parallel segment with the Y-axis to begin with). How would you approach this problem in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $AO$ is perpendicular t0 $AU$:
$$
CR=TU\tan\alpha,\quad
PR=CP-CR=TU(\tan2\alpha-\tan\alpha),\quad
\text{and so on.}
$$

EDIT.

If line $AO$ is not perpendicular to $AU$, then we must have some other info, e.g. the angle between $AO$ (or $AB$) and $y$ axis.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you elaborate in a slightly greater detail as to why you are doing it like this?

Comment: It's simple trigonometry, applied to right triangles $CRA$ and $CPA$.

Comment: Is that assuming that **AO** is parallel to the Y-axis and **CRA** and **CPA** are both right angle triangles?

Comment: Yes, exactly so.

Comment: I see, thank you! Could you see my second edit please?

Comment: My apologies, you are absolutely right.